# Why is this proof that $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational titled as "Proof by infinite descent"?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, infinite-descent, rationality-testing

I am reading [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_by_infinite_descent#Irrationality_of_.E2.88.9A2) wikipedea article on the proof of irrationality of $\sqrt{2}$. It uses the principle of *infinite descent*. I understand it as:

1. We assume $\sqrt{2}=\dfrac pq$, where $p$ and $q$ are some positive integers.
2. We have $2q^2 = p^2 \implies$ $p$ is even, i.e. $p=2r$ for some positive integer $r$.
3. Now we have $2q^2=(2r)^2 \implies q$ is also even, i.e. $q=2s$ for some positive integer $s$.

From steps 1,2 and 3 we conclude that both $p$ and $q$ have $2$ as their factor *at least* one time.  So we can say $\sqrt{2}=\dfrac pq = \dfrac rs$.

Now we can repeat the steps 1,2 and 3 with $\sqrt{2}= \dfrac rs$. This will eventually imply that intezers $r$ and $s$ also have 2 as their factor at least one time, or $r=2r_1$ and $s=2s_2$. Recalling $p=2r$ and $q=2s$  implies that $p$ and $q$ have $2$ as their factor *at least* two number of times.

The notable fact is that we can repeat steps 1,2 and 3 infinite number times, which implies that $p$ and $q$ have 2 as their factor infinite number of times, but this can't be for any finite $p$ and $q$, that is to say their does not exist any intezer which can have 2 as its factor infinite number of times. So we conclude that there doesn't exist any $p$ and $q$ which satisfies $\sqrt 2 = \dfrac pq$, hence $\sqrt 2$ is irrational.

**Question 1:** Do I understand the proof correctly?

**Question 2:** I noted that [this proof](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root_of_2#Proof_by_infinite_descent) on wikipedea is titled as *Proof by infinite descent*, where it does not use the concept of infinite descent at all. So why is it  titled as *Proof by infinite descent*?

Comment: Question 1: yes. Question 2: it is proved so because **it is** a proof by infinite descent. Why do you think it is not?

Comment: @Timbuc 2. Because it doesn't uses the principle of _infinite descent_ at all.

Comment: but it  does: you have a proof in which you begin with something , $\;p/q\;$ , and then from it you get something else $\;r,s\;$, with $\;r/s<p/q\;$ , which fulfills exactly the same as $\;p/q\;$ ...

Comment: @Timbuc It is, but they do not carry it forward, i.e. they just stop without repetition. The correct version is this :http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_by_infinite_descent#Irrationality_of_.E2.88.9A2 here they explain how we repeat the steps infinitely. on the other hand here:http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root_of_2#Proof_by_infinite_descent they do not say anything about infinite descent in the 10 steps.

Comment: the second link talks of a proof by direct contradiction, which is probably the most widely known. The first one seems to be the one you repeat, and to which I refer: it is infinite descent.

Comment: @Timbuc You mean this proof http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root_of_2#Proof_by_infinite_descent   is not a proof by infinite descent, right?

Comment: yes: that one is simply contradiction, perhaps something very similar as the one ancient greeks had. Yet you didn't write in your question this proof, but the other one.

Comment: @Timbuc I think that one is also a proof by infinite descent. You can see the discussion in the answer of User-Pew.

Comment: No infinity descent is used there, as it is not claimed that a smallest fraction exists...etc. It is simply said that both the numerator and the denominator have a common non-trivial divisor, which is a contradiction to the original assumption. Period. The proof you wrote in your question is by infinite descent.

Comment: @Timbuc I had the same doubt( as it is not claimed that a smallest fraction exists...etc). Now to me Wikipedea seems correct(I might be wrong). As pew says in his/her comments that if we replace "irreducible" with "smallest" then the proof exactly fits as a proof by infinite descent.

Answer (score 3):

It would seem that the first proof you linked to, and transcribed in the question, is a proper proof by infinite descent.

The proof in the second link is not a proper proof by infinite descent; it is more or less formulated as a proof of the non-existence of a minimal counterexample. An not even quite that, since the hypothesis used is not that the pair $(a,b)$ is minimal, but that it is reduced (has no common factors); as stated it depends on the preliminary result that all rational numbers can be represented by a reduced fraction. But that dependency could be avoided by rephrasing it to assume a counterexample $(a,b)$ with (say) $a+b$ minimal; clearly this implies easily that $a/b$ is reduced. Also note the reducedness is not used anywhere except at the end to detonate the contradiction; minimality would have done quite as well for that purpose.

Although close in spirit, a proof by infinite descent is not the same as a proof by non-existence of a minimal counterexample. The former establishes from *any* counterexample an (impossible) infinite descending chain of counterexamples. Clearly this implies that a minimal counterexample cannot exist. But a proof of non-existence of a minimal counterexample just needs to derive a contradiction from the supposed existence of a minima counterexample. The contradiction may, but does not have to, derive from the construction of an even smaller counterexample. Only if that is the case, and moreover the minimality is not used in the construction itself, can one convert the proof into one by infinite descent. Since therefore proofs by infinite descent are no easier than by non-existence of a minimal counterexample, possibly harder, and in any case the invariably end with the not very elegant "one can repeat this construction indefinitely, leading to an infinite descent, which is impossible", they are not very popular nowadays.

Proofs by non-existence of a minimal counterexample are of course very close to proofs by induction as well, more precisely of a proof by strong induction of a statement "for any $n$ there are no counterexamples up to stage $n$". But that was not really the question here.

Answer (score 2):

**Answer to Question 1:** Yes, that is one version of the most commonly given ("Pythagorean") proof of the irrationality of $\sqrt 2$.

**Answer to Question 2:** Using the proof you give, you are constructing two *infinite*, *descending* sequences $p_i,q_i$ of natural numbers by repeatedly extracting their common factor $2$. Given that there are only finitely many natural numbers less than a given natural number (in particular, less than your original $p$ and $q$), you have established an impossible infinite descent, so the classification of the proof as a proof by infinite descent is entirely correct.

Comment: 2. No, wikipedea's proof stops at step 10 saying that $gcd(a,b) \neq 1$, which is a contradiction to step 2. Hence $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational. They do not repeat the procedere. Nor they construct $a_i$ and $b_i$.

Comment: @user31782: The Wikipedia proof uses the labels $a,b$ rather than $p,q$ but is otherwise identical to the proof you give in your question. The contradiction derived from a fraction being irreducible being shown as having yet another common factor is *the essence* of the "infinite descent" idea, being made explicit rather than hidden away in the term.

Comment: Note that the [Wikipedia page on *infinite descent*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_by_infinite_descent) states: "An alternative way to express this is to assume one or more solutions or examples exists. Then there must be a smallest solution or example—a minimal counterexample. We then prove that if a smallest solution exists, it must imply the existence of a smaller solution (in some sense)—which again proves that the existence of any solution would lead to a contradiction."

Comment: I have no problem with this article:http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_by_infinite_descent#Irrationality_of_.E2.88.9A2 . I cannot grasp that this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root_of_2#Proof_by_infinite_descent is a proof by infinite descent. In all the 10 steps they don't at all uses the concept of _infinite descent_.

Comment: @user31782: Look at the quote in my above comment. If you replace "smallest" by "irreducible", you will see that this pattern perfectly applies to the linked proof, which shows that if there is a smallest (irreducible) fraction, it can yet be reduced (by $2$).

Comment: Perhaps I got you. I have to go now, I will reply you later. Thank you for explaining.

Comment: $\sqrt 2= \dfrac {\text{numerator}}{\text{denominator}}$, we then say that either denominator or numerator is our solution. Then  $a$ or $b$ are acheived by cancelling out all the common factors, i.e. gcd(a,b)=1, so $a$ or $b$ represents our _smallest_ solution. Then we show that $a$ and $b$ are implying the existence of a smaller solution -- a contradiction of the fact that there exist some smallest solution. This proves that their cannot be a _smallest_ solution. But there should be if $\sqrt 2$ is rational, hence $\sqrt 2$ is not rational.

Comment: If I am getting it right, then there are two types of proof by infinite descent. -----
One in which we assume the smallest solution exist and then show that another smaller solution also exist-- a contradiction of fact that there exist some smallest solution. Hence no solution can exist.

Comment: --------- Second, in which we show that there are infinitely ever-smaller solutions. This  _contradicts_ the fact  that there can be only a finite number of natural-numbers that are smaller than any given one.

Comment: The proof that I've written in my question is of the second kind and this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root_of_2#Proof_by_infinite_descent is of the first kind.

Comment: So now, do I understand everything correctly?

Comment: Your comment beginning with "$\sqrt2$=num./den..." seems to reflect one understanding problem:  $\;\frac{\sqrt a}{\sqrt b}\;$ , with $\;gcd(a,b)=1$ , means the fraction is *reduced*. True, you can also take it as the "smallest" one and then proceed, but the **usual** proof takes *reduced* and arrives to contradiction showing $\;a,\;b\;$ have a common non-trivial divisor. No inf. descent argument is used, though again: if you wanted you can construct it from here. BTW, in the first line in that comment why do you say "either the denominator or the numerator is our solution"? This makes no sense

Comment: @Timbuc I didn't get notified for your comment, that's why I am responding late. $\sqrt 2 =\dfrac ab$ I do not mean $\dfrac{\sqrt{a}}{\sqrt{b}}$. You are taking gcd(a,b) as the solution. I am taking either `den` or `num` as the solution. If gcd is 1 then a and b are the least values of `num and `den` respectively.